# Flutter removeWhere(...) hanging for lists

Tags: flutter

I'm struggling with the following code that is called by a function and it 'hangs'. When the code iterates through the for loop, the first time that it finds a match and tries to remove then it hangs and doesn't continue:

```
for (var anItem in myItems) {
  String s = aFunction(anItem.someField);
  var matches= myItems.where((e) => aFunction(e.someField) == s);

  if (matches.length > 1) {

    myItems.removeWhere((e) => aFunction(e.someField) == s); // Hangs Here
  }
}
```

Comment: in `myItems.where` and `myItems.removeWhere` you have a passed `e` element that is not used in your expression at all - i suggest to read https://dart.dev/guides/libraries/library-tour#collections first

Comment: That's a typo I've fixed - I was removing some extra stuff in the code.

Comment: Yes, it's to remove duplicates based on the field of an object. Refreshing in the app, rather reloading does produce:  Unhandled Exception: Concurrent modification during iteration: Instance(length:9) of '_GrowableList'.